# The conditional expectation $E(f(X) \mid \min(X,t))$ if $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$

Tags: probability-theory, exponential-distribution

> Let $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$, $t \ge 0$ and $Y_t := \min(X,t)$. Let further be $f$ some measurable function with $\mathbb{E}(\lvert f(X) \rvert) < \infty$. Does it hold that:
>
> $$\mathbb{E}(f(X) \mid Y_t) = f(Y_t)I_{[0,t)}(Y_t) + \mathbb{E}_{\{Y_t = t\}}(f(X))I_{\{t\}}(Y_t) \quad?$$

I recognise that the intent here is to split up according to cases:

1. The left summand covers the case that $X<t$, but I do not understand why there is $f(Y_t)$ instead of $\mathbb{E}(f(Y_t))$.
2. The right summand covers the case that $X \ge t$.

So all in all I get the feeling that this identity is true, however, I can not quite see how to argue that the left summand is correct.

For context; here is the definition of conditional expectation from my lecture:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X$ be a real RV with $E(\lvert X \rvert) < \infty$. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ is uniquely defined as a RV via the conditions
>
> 1. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F})$ is $\mathcal{F}$ measurable,
> 2. $\mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) \in L^1(\mathbb{P})$
> 3. $\int_A \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{F}) d \mathbb{P} = \int_A X d \mathbb{P}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: what is $g$ in the expression?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it should have been f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(X)=f(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X<t\}}+f(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geqslant t\}}$ and

$$
\operatorname{E}[f(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X<t\}}|Y_t]=f(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X<t\}}
$$

as $f(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X<t\}}=f(Y_t)\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_t<t\}}$ is $\sigma (Y_t)$ measurable. By the other hand, for every Borel set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ set $A_{\geqslant t}:=A\cap [t,\infty )$ and note that

$$
\{Y_t\in A_{\geqslant t}\}=\{Y_t\in A\}\cap \{Y_t=t\}=\{Y_t\in A\}\cap \{X\geqslant t\}
$$

Then for any chosen Borel set $A$ we find that

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{Y_t\in A\}}\operatorname{E}[f(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geqslant t\}}|Y_t]\,d P&=\int_{\{Y_t\in A\}}\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geqslant t\}}\operatorname{E}[f(X)|Y_t]\,d P\\
&=\int_{\{Y_t\in A_{\geqslant t}\}}\operatorname{E}[f(X)|Y_t]\,d P\\
&=\int_{\{Y_t\in A_{\geqslant t}\}}f(X)\,d P
\end{align*}
$$

as the function $\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geqslant t\}}=\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_t=t\}}$ is $\sigma (Y_t)$-measurable and $\{Y_t\in A_{\geqslant t}\}\in \sigma (Y_t)$. Finally note that
$$
\{Y_t\in A_{\geqslant t}\}=\begin{cases}
\{X\geqslant t\},&\text{ when }t\in A\\
\emptyset ,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore
$$
\operatorname{E}[f(X)\mathbf{1}_{\{X\geqslant t\}}|Y_t]=\mathbf{1}_{\{Y_t=t\}}\operatorname{E}[f(X)|X\geqslant t]
$$
∎

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

Let $s<t$. Then $\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid Y_t=s) = f(s)$ (do you understand why?). If $s=t$ then $\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid Y_t=s) = \mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid X>t) =  \mathbb{E}f(X)1[X>t]$. If $s>t$ then conditioning by $Y>t$ does not make sense since $Y\overset{a.s.}{\leq}t$. All together,

$$\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid Y_t=s) = f(s)1[s<t] + \mathbb{E}f(X)1[X>t]1[s=t].$$

Now, look at your notes and you will find somewhere that
$$
\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid Y) = g(Y)
$$
for appropriate function $g$. But $g(s) = f(s)1[s<t] + \mathbb{E}f(X)1[X>t]$ Hence, $\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid Y) = f(Y)1[Y_t<t] + \mathbb{E}f(X)1[Y=t]$

Comment: this $\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid X>t) =  \mathbb{E}f(X)1[X>t]$ is not right. It must be $\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid X>t) =  \mathbb{E}(f(X)1[X>t])/\mathbb{P}(X>t)$ (assuming that $\mathbb{P}(X>t)>0$)